# how to reverse a words in a string using c# programming?

Tags: c#

I want reverse words in a string. I am not getting proper output. Please help me.

Example

- input: `Hello world`
- output: `World Hello`

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string");
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();           
        string s2 = "";
        int l = s1.Length;

        for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            s2 = s2 + s1[i];
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i<s2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s2[i] == ' ')
            {
                for(int j=i;j>0 && s2[j]!=' ';j--)
                   Console.Write(s2[j1]);
                   Console.Write(" ");
            }
            else if (i == s2.Length - 1)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j > 0 && s2[j] != ' '; j--)
                    Console.Write(s2[j]);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if any one knows please help me

Comment: Take the input, split the string in an array using the space as separator, then iterate it in reverse, from end to begin. Easy, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I think it is esier if you split the string by blanks and then reverse the output array

Comment: See this demo [Reverse String](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XD34C9) :)

Answer (score 4):

Easiest appraoch would be to split the word at its boundaries and then use [`IEnumerable<T>.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var words = myString.Split(' ');
var result = words.Reverse();
```

To combine it all into one string:

```
var resultString = String.Join(" ", result);
```

The final one-liner:

```
var result = String.Join(" ", myString.Split(' ').Reverse());
```

Comment: and then String.Join(" ", result); to rebuild the string

Comment: and it should be `words.Reverse()`.

Comment: @IvanSignore Yeap, updated.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the built-in Linq method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input string");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string reversed = string.Join(" " , input.Split(' ').Reverse());
```

Comment: Didn't notice you wanted to reverse the word order and not the characters. Fixed it, it fits your goals now.

Comment: happy to help! upvote me if you liked it :D